# Which design pattern is appropriate for "Sea Battle" game objects?

Tags: design-patterns, 2d-games

### The problems of my design are:

- I have to copy too many attributes from the interface
- Static field "count" doesn't work for each of successor.

[image]

The field should count for example how many mines are on the game field ([approximate diagram](http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=efebc454a6c7037ffe55d40865c3ef9c)).

I am sorry about mistakes. I am a novice and it is my first question here. Thank you for  corrections and advices.

Comment: Don't rush into the question. Give a brief introduction of what you're trying to achieve. Especially explain what attributes you have to copy from what interface. And what successor you mean. Anyway, I would split the field into cells and let `Cell` reference a `SeaObject`, which can be `Mine`, `Fregate` etc. (btw. the generalization arrows are in the wrong direction). You don't really need the cell class, its properties could all be handled by arrays in `Field`. That's your choice.

Comment: Which are the attributes you have to copy from the interface ?

Comment: Yes, you are right: I use an array of integers in `Field` class and fill it in dependence of `SeaObject` type .`SeaObject` contains `points`that should be putted in the cell with respect to the action ( -1 for mine, +1 for kreyser, etc...). Moreover I want to count objects when I create new one, because I need to limit their number.

Comment: @NicoSchertler ,Yes, you are right: I use an array of integers in Field class and fill it in dependence of SeaObject type .SeaObject contains pointsthat should be putted in the cell with respect to the action ( -1 for mine, +1 for kreyser, etc...). Moreover I want to count objects when I create new one, because I need to limit their number.I agree that my decision to use abstract class Sea Object is not quite right. If the better choice exists I would use it.

Comment: @gontard , I am sorry for doing stupid things:[ , but I have used static field count in base class and I don't understand how to use it. So I copy the property to derived classes (mine,...). Please give advice. Because I constantly try to make similar task and always make cruel code.

Comment: So your problem is "how to properly initialize the `field` with a limited amount of `mines`, a limited amount of `kreyser`, a limited amount of `frigates` ?"

Comment: I was on the hunt for answer and it is here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184089/which-design-pattern-is-appropriate-for-countable-objects?lq=1]